# java rest service through forbidden 403 error

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, web-services, tomcat7

I'm using java to build web api using rest service.
I have add is filter to my web.xml but post request return forbidden 403 error 
but when I use get request it works fine.

```
    <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>POST,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
     <init-param>
          <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
          <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Here's postman view 
[image]

Comment: which url are concerned by your post requests failure ?

Comment: this one http://192.168.0.83:8080/SHMA/SHMA/auth1/data1

Answer (score 0):

When POST is used, the intention from client is to create a resource.

For example, 

`POST /api/apples/
BODY {color: "green"}`

Client issuing this with the intention to create a *create* apple object at the server side.

GET in other hand is retrieve an object/objects from the server.

For example,

`GET /api/apples/`

It returns all apples.

If the client posts to an URL and gets [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), it means that your application does not have permission to create object in the server.

Answer (score -1):

add below dependency in your project it's because of the version mismatch of the httpclient. try using version 4.5.3

[maven repo link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3)